# NetSuite Saved Search: Showing line items that match a child item but also show line items that don't have a child?

Tags: mysql, sql, netsuite, suitescript, saved-searches

I am trying to show a specific field on a child record, but I also don't want to exclude line items that don't have a child record, I am unsure how to achieve this... This is what I had tried (and wouldn't work on my Transaction saved search):

- for my criteria (where the formula should equal 1):

`CASE {custrecord.item} WHEN {item} THEN 1 WHEN NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`

- for my Results:

`CASE {custrecord.item} WHEN NULL THEN NULL ELSE {custrecord.lplotnumber} END`

Doing this excluded line items that didn't have a child, but I wanted those lines to display just blank the resulting field out.

---

**Added details:**

Here is an example table of what I'd like to see:

| {Item} | formula for {custrecord.lplotnumber} | Theoretical {custrecord.item} |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234567 |  | 1234567 (this wouldn't actually exist) |
| 2345678 | LP1234567 | 2345678 (this would exist) |
| 3456789 | LP2345678 | 3456789 (this would exist) |
| 4567891 |  | 4567891 (this wouldn't actually exist) |

I want it to show the correct {custrecord.lplotnumber} by matching the item to the custom record item, but I don't want to exclude the lines that don't have a matching custom record item.

Here is an example table of what I'm actually seeing currently:

| {Item} | {custrecord.lplotnumber} | {custrecord.item} |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2345678 | LP1234567 | 2345678 (this would exist) |
| 3456789 | LP2345678 | 3456789 (this would exist) |

It's excluding the lines that don't have a matching custom record item. But if I don't filter my data I get repeating data on every line.

Here is an example of what happens without the filter I am looking for:

| {Item} | {custrecord.lplotnumber} | {custrecord.item} |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234567 |  | 1234567 (this wouldn't actually exist) |
| 1234567 | LP1234567 | 2345678 (this would exist) |
| 1234567 | LP2345678 | 3456789 (this would exist) |
| 1234567 |  | 4567891 (this wouldn't actually exist) |
| 2345678 |  | 1234567 (this wouldn't actually exist) |
| 2345678 | LP1234567 | 2345678 (this would exist) |
| 2345678 | LP2345678 | 3456789 (this would exist) |
| 2345678 |  | 4567891 (this wouldn't actually exist) |
| 3456789 |  | 1234567 (this wouldn't actually exist) |
| 3456789 | LP1234567 | 2345678 (this would exist) |
| 3456789 | LP2345678 | 3456789 (this would exist) |
| 3456789 |  | 4567891 (this wouldn't actually exist) |
| 4567891 |  | 1234567 (this wouldn't actually exist) |
| 4567891 | LP1234567 | 2345678 (this would exist) |
| 4567891 | LP2345678 | 3456789 (this would exist) |
| 4567891 |  | 4567891 (this wouldn't actually exist) |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your formula is fine. Try switching Equals 1 to Does Not Equal 0.

You could also try:
CASE WHEN LENGTH({custrecord.item}) > 0 AND {custrecord.item} <> {item} THEN 0 ELSE 1 END

Again, Not Equal To 0

Comment: This worked! I had to adjust my formula slightly, but I never thought to try not equal to 0... My final formula was this in the criteria set to not equal to 0:

CASE WHEN {custrecord.item} <> {item} THEN 0 ELSE 1 END

For the Results I didn't use a formula, just called the fields I wanted to show.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your issue accurately, you should not need to apply a filter related to the child record at all.  Simply add the field from the child record to your results.  For rows where that value exists, you should see the value; and where it does not, the field should be blank.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for the reply, when I don't use any filter I get the same line repeated for as many custom records there are. I think I did a bad job explaining, so my custom record is associated to the sales order transaction, but not to the line item on the sales order specifically, but the custom record is made based on my line item data, so there will be 1 for every line item that has been picked/packed. I don't want duplicate lines so I compare line item to custom record item, but I also want to show line items without any matched custom record item...

Comment: I'm not sure I follow...could you add tables to your question details showing the results you get and what you expect/desire?  Also a bit more info about the custom record you're pulling in - you say it's linked at the sales order transaction level, but the data it contains is based on the line item data...?  I'm guessing you will still have to remove any filter based on the custom record, and either filter within the results using a result formula, or use grouping and summary functions to display the results you want to see.  In any case, the more details you provide the more we can help.

Comment: I added detail to the question details, I hope this helps/makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I recreated your example of what happens without the filter and added 2 columns in excel to help illustrate the solution.

[image]

In excel you'd use the following formula:  `=IF(D3=A3,B3,"")`

The equivalent of this for a NetSuite saved search is:  `CASE WHEN {item}={custrecord.item} THEN {custrecord.lplotnumber} ELSE 'Exclude' END`

Add that formula as a result column, so you can check your work.  If it works add the same formula to criteria and exclude 'Exclude' values.

If a field used in the formula is throwing an error when null, you can wrap that variable with [NVL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions105.htm) or [NVL2](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions106.htm).

Comment: I appreciate the response, unfortunately this would remove the line items that don't have a matching custom record, I want to show these items as well, I just don't want to see duplicates.

Comment: The solution provided should end up showing the 4 lines from the 1st table you provided.  The one labeled "Here is an example table of what I'd like to see:".  So if that is not what you'd like to see, can you please re-summarize the values to further explain what you would like to see by the end...

Comment: Hello, the 1st table I provided is what I would like to see, but when I use the formula you provided  in my results I get the 3rd table. When I use your table in the criteria I get the 2nd table. Perhaps I am not understanding how you mean?

Comment: Oh I see.  It's because of the Case/If statement.  We're saying if item matches custrecord.item then return custrecord.lplotnumber else null.  If custrecord.lplotnumber is empty I believe NetSuite views this as null.  So the system is excluding NULL and NULL.  I've amended my original answer to work around this.

Comment: Hello, I apologize, it looks like that still didn't work... When I use the formula in the results I am seeing a table similar to table 3 but with Exclude written in the blank columns. When I use the formula in the criteria I am seeing table 2. If the {items} don't have a matching {custrecord.item} then it would meet the criteria of else 'Exclude'... I've also tried modifying your formula to have another when:

CASE WHEN {item} ={custrecord.item} THEN {custrecord.lplotnumber} WHEN {custrecord.item} IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE 'Exclude' END and that still doesn't work... Please help!

Comment: Could you explain how you mean to exclude 'exclude'? Perhaps I am doing it incorrectly, I am simply taking your formula and setting it not equal to 'exclude' which is removing any fields that use that else operator from the case statement.